# Executing a script after a form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I found, on this site a way to submit a `POST` form without leaving the page. In that script, they put instructions on how to have a function take place after the form's been submitted. Here's what the script looked like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$form = $('form');
$form.submit(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
  },'json');
  return false;
});
});​
```

They said, between `function(response){` and `},'json');` you can specify other JavaScript to take place like alerts etc. after the form's been submitted. I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$form = $('form');
$form.submit(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
$('form').hide();
  },'json');
  return false;
});
});
```

Unfortunately, that does not work, can anybody tell me why? I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5yY6/). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work on jsfiddle because your request fails

Comment: @zerkms I see, but I've also tried it with an actual server and it still won't work.

Comment: Define "won't work."  When you debug through the code, what happens?  Does the call-back function get executed at all?  Does the AJAX request succeed?

Comment: @user1090389 It works fine when you have a successful `post` request: http://jsfiddle.net/v5yY6/1/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $.post, the "function(response)" is only called AFTER a successful result, so you have been misinformed about doing work within this function while the server is processing the request.

To continue processing after sending the request to the server, place the $('form').hide() after the $.post call:

```
$form.submit(function(){
  $.post(
    $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), 
    function(response){
    }
    ,'json'
  );
  $('form').hide();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. Set JavaScript variable as `form`, not `$form`. Then use it in jQuery as `$(form)`.
2. The context of `$(this).attr('action')` is the `$.post()` callback, **not** the form. Solution: `$(form)` instead of `$(this)`.

---

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    form = $('form');

    $(form).on('submit', function() {
        $.post($(form).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $('form').hide();
        },'json');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your fiddle worked fine when the form is changed to

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```

And the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ shows that this is a valid syntax and http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2010/04/08/jquery-form-serialize-doesnt-post-submit-and-button-values-duh/ is also a running sample.  If it's not working at all for you then, as silly as this is, do you have a reference to jQuery in your page?

Comment: No. Never post to "#". Keep your real "`action`". It should work by getting to the root of the problem, not patch it up.

Comment: Then use <form action="/echo/html/" method="post"> instead.  The fiddle needs to actually post.  You can use any of the /echo endpoints.